# upper bound for the floating point error for a number

Tags: c, floating-point

There are many questions (and answers) on this subject, but I am too thick to figure it out. In C, for a floating point of a given type, say double:

```
double x;
scanf("%lf", &x);
```

Is there a generic way to calculate an upper bound (as small as possible) for the error between the decimal fraction string passed to `scanf` and the internal representation of what is now in `x`?

If I understand correctly, there is sometimes going to be an error, and it will increase as the absolute value of the decimal fraction increases (in other words, 0.1 will be a bit off, but 100000000.1 will be off by much more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aspect of the C standard is slightly under-specified, but you can expect the conversion from decimal to `double` to be within one [Unit in the Last Place](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Carine.Lucas/TPScilab/JMMuller/ulp-toms.pdf) of the original.

You seem to be looking for a bound on the **absolute** error of the conversion. With the above assumption, you can compute such a bound as a `double` as `DBL_EPSILON * x`. `DBL_EPSILON` is typically 2^-52.

A tighter bound on the error that can have been made during the conversion can be computed as follows:

```
double va = fabs(x);
double error = nextafter(va, +0./0.) - va;
```

The best conversion functions guarantee conversion to half a ULP in default round-to-nearest mode. If you are using conversion functions with this guarantee, you can divide the bound I offer by two.

---

The above applies when the original number represented in decimal is 0 or when its absolute value is comprised between `DBL_MIN` (approx. 2*10^-308) and `DBL_MAX` (approx. 2*10^308). If the non-null decimal number's absolute value is lower than `DBL_MIN`, then the absolute error is only bounded by `DBL_MIN * DBL_EPSILON`. If the absolute value is higher than `DBL_MAX`, you are likely to get infinity as the result of the conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you point me to a reference? Isn't this value a bit too high?

Comment: @Boris I will look for a reference. The formula `DBL_EPSILON * x` is over-approximated by a factor of at most 2. I will complete my answer with a more optimal computation for the ULP.

Comment: @Boris I have placed in the answer a link to a pamphlet written by an expert on the best definition to use of “ULP”. There's a lot on information on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point . Finally, since you are using C, playing with the format `%a` (for printing a `double` with an hexadecimal representation of the mantissa) and the input format `0x1.1239abcp10` for floating-point constants goes a long way towards understanding the representation.

Comment: @Boris Oh, one last thing: I once thought that I could assume decimal-to-floating-point functions from standard libraries to be within 1/2 ULP. I was disappointed, and to cut a long story short, I had to write my own. It is easy if you do not care about performance: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/18/Analyzing-single-precision-floating-point-constants

Answer (score 0):

you cant think of this in terms of base 10, the error is in base 2, which wont necessarily point to a specific decimal place in base 10.

You have two underlying issues with your question, first scanf taking an ascii string and converting it to a binary number, that is one piece of software which uses a number of C libraries.  I have seen for example compile time parsing vs runtime parsing give different conversion results on the same system.  so in terms of error, if you want an exact number convert it yourself and place that binary number in the register/variable, otherwise accept what you get with the conversion and understand there may be rounding or clipping on the conversion that you didnt expect (which results in an accuracy issue, you didnt get the number you expected).

the second and real problem Pascal already answered.  you only have x number if binary places.  In terms of decimal if you had 3 decimal places the number 1.2345 would either have to be represented as 1.234 or 1.235.  same for binary if you have 3 bits of mantissa then 1.0011 is either 1.001 or 1.010 depending on rounding.  the mantissa length for IEEE floating point numbers is well documented you can simply google to find how many binary places you have for each precision.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess the inherent problem is that I have to work with numbers that are already `double`, and I have no knowledge of what the original ascii string was. This is why I need an upper bound on the absolute error. The second paragraph however addresses my question exactly!

Comment: a follow on to this is the confusion folks have when a number that may appear simple in decimal maybe only one or two significant digits, cannot be exactly represented in floating point, it gets worse as you add more digits.  in base 3 for example the number 1/3rd is easy to represent (0.1), but in decimal it becomes an infinitely repeating number which for practical programming purposes you have to clip off at some number of digits. again it snowballs from there and not easy to see from the list of digits in the base 10 number how good or bad it will turn out in floating point.